# Listview with Subitems: Array Adapter Overriding doesn´t work

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I just want a listview with subitems. So I decided to override the arrayadapter like this:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, list) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

                text1.setText("TEST1");
                text2.setText("TEST2");
                return view;
            }
        };
```

The problem is android studio always says: cannot resolve symbol "context"

What can I do against that or do you have a other solution for my problem?

Complete Class:

```
public class ChangelogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<String> items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_changelog);

        final ListView listviewChangelog = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewChangelog);

        items=new ArrayList<String>();

        adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.menu_item,R.id.lvmenuitems,items);
        listviewChangelog.setAdapter(adapter);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, list) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

                text1.setText("TEST1");
                text2.setText("TEST2");
                return view;
            }
        };

        String url = "PLACEHOLDER";

        JsonArrayRequest getRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
                {
                    @Override public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Log.d("Response", response.toString());

                        for (int i=0; i < response.length(); i++)
                        {
                            try {
                                JSONObject oneObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                // Pulling items from the array
                                String Version = oneObject.getString("version");
                                String change_mission = oneObject.getString("change_mission");
                                String change_map = oneObject.getString("change_map");
                                String change_mod = oneObject.getString("change_mod");
                                String note = oneObject.getString("note");


                                if(Version != "" || Version != ";")
                                {
                                    items.add("Update: " + Version);
                                }

                                if(Version != "" || Version != ";")
                                {
                                    items.add("Mission: " + change_mission);
                                }

                                if(Version != "" || Version != ";")
                                {
                                    items.add("Map:" + change_map);
                                }
                                if(Version != "" || Version != ";")
                                {
                                    items.add( "Mod:" + change_mod);
                                }
                                if(Version != "" || Version != ";")
                                {
                                    items.add("Notiz:" + note);
                                }

                                items.add("----------------------------------------------------");

                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                //Not used at this time
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                        //mTextView.setText(error.toString());
                    }
                }
        );
        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(getRequest);



    }
}
```

Comment: Try `YourActivtyName.this` instead of `context`.

Comment: @KNeerajLal Doesnt work

Comment: use recyclerview better than ListView

Comment: @AmanVerma Do you have a Code Example?

Comment: you can find a tutorial over here - http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: for subitem you can have anotherrecyclerview inside each item

Comment: @AmanVerma Ok do you also have an idea why my code doesn´t work?

Comment: Could you post whole class codes?

Comment: @nurisezgin Updated

Comment: I coudnt see context decleration, did you try replace context with this keyword before?

Comment: @nurisezgin I didn´t declarated context. Do I have to declarate it? With what keyword do I have to replace it?

Comment: You should use ChangelogActivity.this instead of context

Comment: @nurisezgin Then it says: Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter(...)

Comment: Error:(56, 32) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(ChangelogActivity,int,int,int)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,Object[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Object[])
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,List) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to List)

Comment: Try to replace **context** with **getApplicationContext()** , it work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is what i say. If you cannot resolve this problem, you will send your code to me. I will fix it and reply you. (nurisezgin.sezgin@gmail.com)

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(ChangeLogActivity.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, new String[]{}){

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        return view;
    }
};
```